# How to compile Typescript to JS that uses ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

My `tsconfig.json` file contains

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "esnext",
    }
}
```

But the compiled JS files still use `exports`/`require` syntax.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

My directory structure is as follows

```
- APIs/
  - emails/
    - sendEmail.ts
  - oldFiles/
    - file1.js
    - file2.js
- index.js
- tsconfig.json
- package.json
```

I am running `tsc` using the command `tsc APIs/emails/sendEmail.ts` from the root directory.

Comment: How are you calling `tsc`?

Comment: from the root folder, i call `tsc a/b/c/file.ts` (the `tsconfig.json` is in the root folder)

Comment: Your edit confirms [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73062007/157247). By calling `tsc` that way, you're not using your `tsconfig.json`. (This is surprising, but true.). Just use `tsc` with appropriate `includes` (see the answer), rather than giving a specific file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those settings are correct, so most likely you're not actually using that `tsconfig.json` file. For instance, if you do `tsc someFile.ts`, `tsc` doesn't use the `tsconfig.json` (surprisingly). Your best bet is probably to add an `includes` to your configuration (so `tsc` knows what it's compiling) and then compile simply by invoking `tsc`, which *will* look for a local `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Then in `package.json` (for instance):

```json
// ...
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
}
// ...
```

Comment: Also, how can I exclude `.js` files from being compiled? Should I just add `**/*.js` to the `exclude` field?

Comment: @WillZap - Yes, or what I usually do is output to a different directory entirely (`dist`) and exclude that.

Answer (score -1):

This config should work. But it's `tsconfig.json` not `tsconfig.js`.

Comment: Oh it is tsconfig.json, made a typo in the question

Comment: @WillZap show your directory structure and where you run `tsc`.

Comment: I edited the question to show my dir structure and how I run `tsc`